# uglifier and concat grunt plugins don't work togheter

Tags: gruntjs

i am wondering what is wrong with my grunfile.js file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // 1. All configuration goes here 
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        concat: {   
    dist: {
        src: [
            'js/libs/*.js', // All JS in the js folder
            'js/global.js',

        ],
        dest: 'js/production/production.js',
    }
},

uglify: {
    build: {
        src: 'js/production/production.js',
        dest: 'js/production/production.min.js'
    }
}



    });

    // 3. Where we tell Grunt we plan to use this plug-in.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat', 'grunt-contrib-uglify');


    // 4. Where we tell Grunt what to do when we type "grunt" into the terminal.
   grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

i keep having this error: "Task uglify not found. use --force to continue."

i'm following coyer's tutorial (http://24ways.org/2013/grunt-is-not-weird-and-hard/#fn167318486852a968d2ca848) but i can't figure out how to add a chunk of code AFTER another.

the `concat` plugin works alone, but as i add the `uglify` one, i get the error. it's probably syntax but i can't figure it out (i moved the code around, repeated the whole block etc.) nothing works.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a scope problem with your targets I guess.

Note that you use 'dist' for concat, while you use 'build' for uglify as so called targets.
Try using both 'dist' for example.

Look here for further infos on targets:
http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets

By specifying them in your registered default task, you could also overcome that problem, if you really need the difference in the target's names.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:dist', 'uglify:build'])
```

EDIT:

As I reread your question, I saw you load your NpmTasks in only one function, comma separated. 
As stated here (http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) they have to be loaded in single lines, each for themselves, like so:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
```

Comment: thank you so much, the dist/build thing and the grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat:dist', 'uglify:build']) in a single function was the problem. now working, thanks so much!